# DOM querySelectorAll - element ID not starting with

Tags: dom, filter, selectors-api

In an HTML document I have a large inline SVG object with groups bearing a variety of IDs (or none at all).  I want to find all groups other than those whose IDs start with the letter sequences `l0pzlo`, `l1pzlo`and `l2pzlo`.  The task of finding just those IDs is easy

```
element.querySelectorAll("[id^=l0pzlo_],[id^=l1pzlo_],[id^=l2pzlo_]")
```

does the trick.  However, I cannot work out how to get only those elements whose IDs **DO NOT** start with any of the three prefixes given above.  I have attempted to use `:not`in a variety of different ways, e.g.

```
element.querySelectorAll(:not('[(id^=l0pzlo)]'))";
```

but nothing seems to be to the liking of the browser.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be more useful to leave my own answer here rather than just delete the question

```
element.querySelectorAll('*:not([id^=l0pzlo]):not([id^=l1pzlo]):not([id^=l2pzlo])');
```

works.  Think of it as going about the task of filtering in a non-greedy way.  First you get absolutely everything and then progressively filter out what you don't need with a sequence of one or more `:not`s

Comment: Thanks for leaving it there ;) Yet I suspect you left out the trailing `'`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - corrected the typo